# Sign and verify a file

Tags: ios, objective-c, cryptography

I have some pretty simple requirements and I'm surprised how difficult this is: I want to sign a file, get the signature as base64 for transmission, and then verify that signature on iOS and OS X in Objective C.  Here's what I've got already.

Generating the signature is fairly easy — for my purposes this can be done on the command line.  First generate the keys:

```
openssl genrsa -out rsa_priv.pem 1024
openssl rsa -in rsa_priv.pem -pubout -outform DER -out rsa_pub.der
openssl req -new -x509 -key rsa_priv.pem -out rsa_cert.cer
```

I want to do the verification as part of a framework so don't want to bundle the certificate as a file, so I get the base64 encoded version and then decode it before verification:

```
openssl enc -base64 -in rsa_cert.cer
```

To create a signature for a file:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -sign rsa_priv.pem FILE | openssl enc -base64
```

So now I have a base64 encoded signature and base64 encoded X509 certificate.  I've looked at various stack overflow posts and the CryptoCompatibility example and have the following code to load the certificate:

```
NSData *certD = [self decodeBase64:base64Certificate];
NSAssert(certD != nil, @"Could not load certificate");
CFDataRef certData = CFBridgingRetain(certD);
SecCertificateRef publicCertificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), certData);
NSAssert(publicCertificate != NULL, @"Invalid public certificate");
CFRelease(certData);

SecPolicyRef policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
SecTrustRef trustRef;
OSStatus trustResult = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(publicCertificate, policy, &trustRef);
NSAssert1(trustResult == 0, @"Bad trust result: %d", trustResult);
SecTrustResultType trustEvalResult;
trustResult = SecTrustEvaluate(trustRef, &trustEvalResult);
NSAssert1(trustResult == 0, @"Bad trust eval result: %d", trustResult);
NSAssert1(trustEvalResult == kSecTrustResultProceed, @"Trust eval result not proceed: %d", trustEvalResult);
keyRef = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trustRef);
NSAssert(keyRef != NULL, @"Could not copy public key");
CFRelease(policy);
CFRelease(trustRef);
```

The decodeBase64 method is copied from the CryptoCompatibility example:

```
const char * stringC = [base64String UTF8String];
size_t stringCLength = strlen(stringC);

NSMutableData * result = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((stringCLength + 3) / 4) * 3];
int bytesDecoded = b64_pton(stringC, [result mutableBytes], [result length]);
if (bytesDecoded < 0) {
    result = nil;
} else {
    [result setLength: (NSUInteger) bytesDecoded];
}
return result;
```

This fails when evaluating the trust:

```
"Trust eval result not proceed: 6":
kSecTrustResultFatalTrustFailure
Trust denied; no simple fix is available. For example, if a certificate cannot be
verified because it is corrupted, trust cannot be established without replacing the
certificate. This value may be returned by the SecTrustEvaluate function but not stored
as part of the user trust settings.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my certificate was not DER encoded:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in rsa_cert.cer -out rsa_cert.der
```